# How can I stylize the text of a WPF button control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Having worked with FXML and seen the similarities between FXML CSS styling and XAML ResourceDictionary for styling.

with FXML i was able to style the label of a button such that it had an inner-shadow effect.

I am trying to do the same with buttons in XAML.

I don't need the exact code to implement the style, I just need to know where that code goes in the  tag in the resource dictionary.

How can I go about styling the text of XAML button?

### EDIT

I want to thank McGarnagle for getting me set in the right direction : 
This is with what I was able to come up (thanks to a bit I was able to get from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/EngraveText.htm))

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-2" Y="-2" />
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "the label of a button" in WPF. that java stuff is actually a poorly designed imitation of what .Net provides, pretty much like everything else in java. Read about the [WPF Content Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [Visual Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to understand better how WPF UI elements are composed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add effects to any element using the `Effect` property and adding a `DropShadowEffect`.  If you want to blur only the text inside a button, then you will have to override the control template.  Here is a simple example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" />
                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                    <TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To re-create the default button style with a drop shadow, just copy-paste the [default control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add the drop-shadow effect to the content element.  To do this you'll have to replace the `ContentPresenter` element with a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Margin="2"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                >
    <ContentControl.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" />
    </ContentControl.Effect>
</ContentControl>
```

[image: drop-shadow button]

Comment: That's close to what I'm going for but it's not exact.
What I'm looking for is an inner-shadow effect, where the text looks engraved, rather than the text casting a shadow.

Comment: @Will hm, they used to have "EmbossBitmapEffect", but apparently that is obsolete and there's nothing to replace it.  You could always hijack the relevant effect from here: http://wpffx.codeplex.com/

Comment: I found something on Java2S that seems to be exactly for what I am looking. I haven't tested it yet but http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/EngraveText.htm

Answer (score 0):

Page and not button but I think this is what you are asking.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridHeaderStyleRight" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="4,4,4,4" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will customize the default button style for all buttons used in the current app:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <!-- Change whatever you want. -->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                     <!-- Custom Template -->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```